# disable Wordpress Short Links

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I have a wordpress template working with the bridge theme and visual composer that wont disable the shortlinks and i've tried all the standard ways to disable them:

```
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_shortlink_wp_head', 10, 0);
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_shortlink_wp_head');
remove_action('wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head');
```

Comment: The code in this answer did the trick for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62577318/how-to-remove-or-disable-rel-shortlink-url-with-post-id-in-http-response-header

Answer (score 0):

This should work just fine, but I can see that you have already tried it:

```
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_shortlink_wp_head', 10, 0);
```

Are you putting this in your functions.php file? Please make sure you did not put it in the middle of a function.