# How to remove or disable rel shortlink url with post id in http response header for wordpress 5+ and and below, without a plugin?

Tags: wordpress, apache, content-security-policy

When you inspect your `blog post` in the `Network` tab of your `Chrome` browser, it looks like below:

```
Response Headers
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
.....
.....
.....
link:<https://demo.com/?p=53>; rel=shortlink
server:Apache
.....
status:200
vary:Accept-Encoding
.....
.....
```

This exposes your blog `post id`

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is as below in your `functions.php` file

add_filter('after_setup_theme', 'my_disable_rel_shortlink');

function my_disable_rel_shortlink() {
remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'wp_shortlink_header', 11);
}